# Discord.js(); How to send file (It always sends a 0 byte file?)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm having trouble sending a file after downloading using ytdl. I notice it's very strange, it will successfully send the file to the server provided that I name it manually something other than the title... otherwise it only sends a 0 byte file to my server. I tried running all sorts of string methods on my title scheme thinking that could be wrong, but that didn't work. I have a hunch that maybe it's related to: 
https://github.com/hydrabolt/discord.js/issues/1907

But man I have no idea I'm clueless. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is my source. Function im having issues sending the file is command === 'ytm'

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');  //need discord.js library of course.
const config = require("./config.json"); //load up the token and prefix from our object configuration file.
const bot = new Discord.Client();  //establishing the bot as the client. "bot" means "client" when looking at the documentation!


bot.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('I am ready!');
});

bot.on('message', message => {

  if(message.author.bot) return; //prevents the bot from reacting to itself.
  if(message.content.indexOf(config.prefix) !== 0) return; //reads out the first character of the message, and if its not our prefix we don't do break away

  const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g); //setting up to split things into arguments for handling commands, and usage of the prefix
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === 'ping') {
    message.channel.send('pong');
    //console.log(args);
    //console.log(command);
  }


  if (command === 'ytm') {
     const fs = require('fs');
     const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
     url = args[0];
     //console.log(ytdl.getURLVideoID(url));
     //tried to actually work with the "title" information outside of the callback. apparently impossible? 
     ytdl.getInfo(url,function(err, info){
         var title = info['title'];
         var length = title.length;
         title = title.substring(0, (length / 3));
         title = title.trim();
         title = './' + title + '.mp3'
         console.log(title);
         //console.log(info['size']);
         ytdl(url, {filter:'audioonly', format:'mp3'}).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(title.toString()));
         message.channel.send("Here's your mp3, boi.", {files:[(title)]}); 
         //message.channel.sendFile(('./' + title), title, 'Heres your mp3, boi,'); //deprecated?      
         })

  }





});

bot.login(config.token);
```

Comment: Can't this be kinda illegal because of copyright?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you're attempting to send the title variable as your file which you've explicitly set as a string by doing `title = './' + title + '.mp3'`. Your issue is that you're attempting to send a video *stream* instead of a video *file*. ytdl-core is a module that's made explicity for *streaming videos* instead of *downloading videos*. To get and send an MP3 file, you have to use [youtube-dl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-dl) instead (what ytdl-core is based off of). This will emit an event when the file has finished downloading, which you can then send through Discord.js.